# Using Apollo+Vue: What parameters are given to the "update" callback?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, graphql, apollo-client

This is a syntax question related to Javascript.  I'm following along with this GraphQL tutorial:
https://www.howtographql.com/vue-apollo/4-routing/

The this.$apollo.mutate has a callback in it called "update" that takes a "data" parameter as follows:

```
update: (store, { data: { createLink } }) => {
    const data = store.readQuery({
        query: ALL_LINKS_QUERY
    })
    data.allLinks.push(createLink)
    store.writeQuery({ query: ALL_LINKS_QUERY, data })
}
```

What is "{ data: { createLink } }"?  Is this an object?  While the "createLink" parameter is defined inside the body of the arrow function, "data" is not.  Dumb question, but I have no idea what this is even called to be able to research it (JS beginner).  It looks like ES6 destructuring, but I can't find a similar example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is object destructuring. It will create a new variable named `createLink`. It's code in ES5 is:

```
update: (store, params2) {
  const createLink = params2.data.createLink
  ...
}
```

You can read more about it in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Nested_object_and_array_destructuring